# Best way to generate a random background colour with php on page load

Tags: php, random, colors, background, pageload

I am trying to create some code that generates a random background colour on page load, but also out puts text with a colour dependant on the background colour. EG if the background colour is dark, it will display light text.

So far I have created the following, which works - though i'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve it.

I created an array that decides at random whether the background colour should be light or dark, and have done this so I can have two alternate font colours based on the $scheme. Im sure there will be a much more dynamic way to do this?

Then I have set two more arrays listing multiple colours for both the dark and light schemes, with an elseif statement to output the relevant css.

There is a couple of things about this that i'd like to query:

1) why is the last string in an array never outputted? it make it so I have to add a blank string in every array just so the one prior isn't omitted.

2) what is the best practice to achieve this, as well as the most dynamic method.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");


$input = array("dark", "light", "");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

$scheme = $input[$rand_keys[0]];


if ($scheme == "dark") {

$darkBg = array('212a34', '383838', '000');
$rand_keys_1 = array_rand($input, 2);

$bg_colour = $darkBg[$rand_keys_1[0]];

echo 'body {background-color:#' . "$bg_colour" . '}';
echo 'h2 { color:#fff; }';

}

elseif ($scheme == "light") {

$lightBg = array('ebecee', '31a989', 'fff');
$rand_keys_2 = array_rand($input, 2);

$bg_colour = $lightBg[$rand_keys_2[0]];

echo 'body {background-color:#' . "$bg_colour" . '}' ;
    echo 'h2 { color:#000; }'; 

}

else { echo 'body {background-color: #ef3c39;}'; }


?>
```

// Should probably have noted, It will be a predefined list of colours

Comment: i would hate to visit a site that did this

Comment: *aaahhhhhhhhhhh....* my eyes! O.o

Comment: Calm down, It's just a learning project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I have found a better method to be the following in terms of reducing the amount of code, getting a better random distribution and also more dynamic.

```
<?php

$bgColours = array(

"414245"=>"dark", //one
"333333"=>"dark", //two
"e25359"=>"dark", //three
"ebeced"=>"light", //six
"edd6b4"=>"light" //seven

);

$bgColour = (array_rand($bgColours,1));

$colourScheme = $bgColours[$bgColour];

if ("$colourScheme" == "dark") {

 echo 'body {background-color:#' . "$bgColour" . '}';
 echo 'h2 { color:#fff; }';
}

elseif ($colourScheme == "light") {

echo 'body {background-color:#' . "$bgColour" . '}' ;
    echo 'h2 { color:#333333; }'; 

}

else  { echo 'body {background-color: #ef3c39;}'; }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
echo dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
```

if you want random from a set of known colors you do the following:

```
$colors = array($color1, $color2);
echo $colors[array_rand($colors)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, thought I forgot to mention that it would be for a predefined colour palette.

Nice bit of code me me to look into and learn though.

Comment: You can set an array of colors like $colors = array($color1, $color2) and then call $colors[array_rand($colors)]

Answer (score 0):

As Dagon has said this sounds like a horrible idea for a UI but here is how I would do it:

```
//starts off with dark text
$textcolor = '222222';

$rand1 = rand(0,255);
$rand2 = rand(0,255);
$rand3 = rand(0,255);

$bgcolor = sprintf("%02X",$rand1) . sprintf("%02X",$rand2) . sprintf("%02X",$rand3);

$total = $rand1 + $rand2 + $rand3;
//if total is less than 400 it is most likely a darker color unless one or more color is accounting for most of the 400
if($total < 400 && $rand1 < 180 && $rand2 < 180 && $rand3 < 180) {
    $textcolor = 'dddddd';
}
```

It isn't perfect but 99% of the time the text is readable compared to the background.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, though I should have mentioned initially that its for a predefined list of colours.